# list all variables in Tcl file?

Tags: variables, environment-variables, tcl, dump

I'm a newer to learn tcl.

I have some variables in tcl files(var.tcl) which list the variables predefined by other user
example in var.tcl:

```
set tool1 ""
set tool2 "${tools1}somepath"
set tool3 "${tools2}somepath"
set tool4 "${tool1}somepath"
```

And now I have to source var.tcl and dumpy all this variables for checking all setting

code :

```
source var.tcl
# dump or list all variables in var.tcl
```

How to dump all variables in var.tcl?
Could anyone help me?
thanks for your responding

Comment: Check the [`info`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/info.htm) man page. You're looking for `info vars` and/or `info globals`

Comment: Thanks for help, I solve the problems using info. :)
for other user has same problem please search key word as below:
info vars ?pattern?

Comment: You probably want to check what's present before calling `source` and after and compare the two.

Comment: @glennjackman: Can you please post you answer as an answer, such that it can be accept if afterwards? Thank you.